# Firestore returns invalid-argument while adding new data in react native ios

Tags: ios, database, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

Im using firebase in React native which works fine on Android side but on IOS when i try to add item its show me this error.

[Error: [firestore/invalid-argument] Client specified an invalid argument. Note that this differs from failed-precondition. invalid-argument indicates arguments that are problematic regardless of the state of the system (e.g., an invalid field name).]

```
 let story = firestore().collection('paidItems').doc();

        await story.set({ 
            id: story.id,
            name: title,
            url : image,
            passLink,
            password,
            createdAt: firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        });
```

Already try **new Object()** **Object.assign({}, data)**

Thanks.

Comment: I dont think you can set a document if you dont know the doc id of that document. You need to pass a doc id inside doc() for set method to work. If you are adding a new document you can use .add method instead

Answer (score 4):

After suffering alot I fond the solution,
basically Im trying to upload an **base64** image and for IOS side the size of the image is too large thats why it create problem.

When i specify the image size to 400x400 its work on both IOS and ANDROID.

Comment: Yes, it is working but for ios you have to reduce image quality.
For that, if you are using react-native-image-crop-picker this lib, then add these line       
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      compressImageMaxWidth: 300,
      compressImageMaxHeight: 300,
      compressImageQuality: 0.4,

Answer (score 2):

Check your firestore rules.

I was getting the same error and that was due to incorrect firestore rules.

Incorrect:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: true;
    }
  }
}
```

> I actually forgot to put `if`

Correct:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Also, the formatting of your rules matters. My IDE added spaces and that turned out to be my issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
let story = firestore().collection('paidItems').doc();
```

Doc can't be empty, it expects parameter which you didn't provide.

However to add item, you can simply it like below.

```
let story = firestore().collection('paidItems');
let storyRes = await story.add({ 
            name: title,
            url : image,
            passLink,
            password,
            createdAt: firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        });
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. 
ok let me try. 
But i have on exception if this is the solution then why it is working on android side.

Comment: I don't know about that, but above is a standard way if you want to add any new doc

Comment: Still facing the same error after modifying. :(

```[Error: [firestore/invalid-argument] Client specified an invalid argument. Note that this differs from failed-precondition. invalid-argument indicates arguments that are problematic regardless of the state of the system (e.g., an invalid field name).]```